# Accessing integer resources in xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I have read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer) where found that how to access integer resources in java class but no docs for another resource.

Here is Resources at res/values/integers.xml

```
<resources>
     <integer name="input_field_padding" >5</integer>
</resources>
```

Tried to access the input_field_padding in EditText.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:padding="@integer/input_field_padding" />
```

But I got the following exception

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x10
```

Is it possible to access it in another resources file or am I missing something?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Finally I am able to access integer resource in java code and integer value as dimen in xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="input_field_padding">20dip</dimen>
    <integer name="input_field_padding">20</integer>
</resources>
```

In xml file:-

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:padding="@dimen/input_field_padding" />
```

In java file:-

```
EditText mUsername = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
//int padding = this.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.input_field_padding);
int padding = (int) this.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.input_field_padding);
mUsername.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
```

Comment: This answer is mis-guiding. And depending on use case, wrong. Please see my answer below.

Comment: You've created the integer, which isn't illegal, but is non-standard, but then you never use it.  You've only used the dimen that you created with the same name as the integer.  This is bad practice at the least.

Comment: @DavidMays Yes, the commented line isn't illegal and it worked for me. According to your suggestion I updated it.

Comment: You must use this in XML like : @integer/input_field_padding

Comment: I am surprised why there are so many upvote on this, in fact, you use a dimen not integer.

Comment: This worked for me:                                                                                                 int width = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.review_first_column_width);

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is completely mis-guiding. Unless there is a specific unique reason, you should never use an Integer resource for setting padding sizes. Not only in XML but also in code. This is why you experienced an `UnsupportedOperationException`. Integer resources are not scaled based on the DPI of screens. Which means you will not get consistently spaced padding for all devices. Dimen resources will automatically adjust their value for you.  Your java code should look like this:

```
EditText mUsername = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
int padding = (int) this.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.input_field_padding);
mUsername.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
```

Which, btw, there's no need to set the padding of the `EditText` element in code if you already set it in the XML. Unless you wanted to change it to a different value at run time.

Read more here: 
[Density Independence](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence)
[Working with XML Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Comment: Shouldn't your second line be ```R.dimen.input_field_padding``` ?

Comment: Oops. Missed adjusting that when I copied/pasted.  Thanx!

Comment: This makes the padding smaller for me than if I just created the view directly in xml. Why?

Answer (score 4):

Also You Can Define It This Way :

```
<resources>
<item name="text_line_spacing" format="integer" type="dimen">10</item>
</resources>
```

Format = enclosing data type:

float
boolean
fraction
integer
...
and type stands for:

Type = resource type (referenced with R.XXXXX.name):

color
dimen
string
style
etc...

Access It Like This :

```
Resources res = getResources();
int i= res.getInteger(R.dimen.int_value);
```

Comment: can i use whatever i want for type or is there a set of possible strings ?

Comment: color,dimen,string,style,etc

Answer (score 2):

if you are taking Integer resource then you have to take R.Integer.yourintvalue like this way

```
int value=(int) contextG.getResources()
            .getDimension(R.integer.myvalue);
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to access an integer field is using `@integer/input_field_padding`

In XML

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:padding="@dimen/input_field_padding" />
```

In JAVA

```
R.integer.integer_name
```

Refer this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer .

Comment: Agreed, this is the right way to do it. For reference, my `integer_name` value is in `values/integers.xml` like this: `<integer name="integer_name">42</integer>`

Comment: Using `R.integer.integer_name` directly is wrong! It just holds the `resource id` of the integer. you should use `getResources().getInteger(R.integer.SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY)` as mentioned in Arash's answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/23267383/4718314 )

Answer (score -1):

```
 <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

> android:text="@integer/imageSelectLimit"

```
       android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
       android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"/>
```