# Absolute positioning in layout Android

Tags: android, calendar

I have a calendar view and I am trying to get the lines denoting every half-hour and every hour to be spaced 60 and 120 dp apart (for mdpi). When viewed on a devices that is hdpi or xhdpi the layout is not spaced evenly apart. Here is my layout for the lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/calDemarcations"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View android:id="@+id/currTime"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <View android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View android:id="@+id/calFirstDemarc"
        android:layout_marginTop="55.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View android:layout_marginTop="55.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View android:layout_marginTop="55.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View android:layout_marginTop="55.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View android:layout_marginTop="55.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View android:layout_marginTop="55.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View android:layout_marginTop="55.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View android:layout_marginTop="55.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View android:layout_marginTop="55.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View android:id="@+id/calLastD"
        android:layout_marginTop="55.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How would I get this to display properly across all screen densities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use  and create values-mdpi, values-xhdpi and values-hdpi. Then set your margin using the dimen.

For example in XML: [Accessing integer resources in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230026/accessing-integer-resources-in-xml)

or in java: [How to set text size of textview dynamically for different screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494037/how-to-set-text-size-of-textview-dynamically-for-diffrent-screens)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I made the values folders and everything looks good now.