# image not resize in 600dp android device

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I try to make my homepage for all device resolution and for that I use layout-small,layout-normal,layout-large it's OK for normal device but problem happens when device resolution go high. I post some image of what happen in there:

7inch Device with fullHD resolution:

[image]

7inch Device with 480*800 resolution:
[image]

Ass you see in FullHD the buttons not scale I post my xmls for them now:
 note: in fullHD you can see 600dpi in whit board under green title it show that it use layout-sw600dp and xml code for this layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/main_logo_back_draw" >

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/title_background_main" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center|left"
             >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_refresh"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/refresh_main_icon" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/img_notification"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="9sp"
                android:gravity="top|right"
                android:background="@drawable/notification_main_icon" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_textsize"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/fontsize_main_icon" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_main_icon" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout  android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#c8c8c8"
        android:alpha="0.6" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/time_date_main_draw" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/calender_logo_main_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Date: "
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_date_milady"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="####/##/##"
            android:textSize="8sp" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <LinearLayout  
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="#d7d7d7"  >
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_date_shamsi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="####/##/##"
            android:textSize="8sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="600dpi "
            android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/calender_logo_main_icon" />

        <LinearLayout  
            android:layout_width="0.5dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="#d7d7d7" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <DigitalClock
            android:id="@+id/digitalClock1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="8sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ساعت: "
            android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/clock_logo_main_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout  android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/dock_hold_main_icon" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_oghatshari"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"

            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pray_main_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_abohava"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"

            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"

            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/air_main_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_about"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"

            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/info_main" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_map"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"

            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"

            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/map_main_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout  android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/dock_hold_main_icon" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_hire"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/estekhdam_main_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_second"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/seckala_main_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_cars"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/car_main_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/house_main_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout  android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/dock_hold_main_icon" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_bus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bus_main_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_train"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/train_main_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_airplan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/airplane_main_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_ads"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/comericals_main_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout  android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" 
        android:background="@drawable/dock_hold_main_icon">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_contact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/contact_main_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_about_us"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/about_main_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_dlesson"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/digital_question_main_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_news"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/news_main_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

all layout is the same code except in  this layout i set size to first column to see if it's worked but it's not:(
can any one tell me what do I wrong ???

Edit: I have all layout folder in my project layout-small, medium , large ,xlarge ... and even layout-sw600dp.

[image]

Comment: I forgot to say both device is 4.4.2

Comment: you can use 9patch png

Comment: Thanks but what is 9patch png ???

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html go to this link you will undersatnd

Comment: Put your icons in xhdpi  and xxhdpi resolution in drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi folder respectively, http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html link will help you.

Comment: Thanks for comment I Already have them not chance of working :(

Comment: and for 9patch png it's not change any thing I'm wonder in xml show in eclispe it's complicity show the changes but in device nothing change.

Comment: Make sure your icons in following dimensions 48 × 48 (mdpi) 72 × 72 (hdpi) 96 × 96 (xhdpi) 144 × 144 (xxhdpi) 192 × 192 (xxxhdpi)

Comment: the icons have different dimensions but not what you say I read android developer guide:
    36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
    48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
    72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
    96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
    180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
    192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density (launcher icon only; see note above)

Comment: I don't use the exact same density but what ever my low-density is the medium is1.5x and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this in your `<ImageView>`?

```
android:scaleType = "fitCenter"
android:adjustViewBounds = "true"
```

Btw, I suggest you to change your approach. Try to change the image size with `<dimen>`, its a lot more easy to use and maintain rather than creating one xml file for each display type.

See [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html) for more information, this [may](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230026/accessing-integer-resources-in-xml) help you as well.

**EDIT**

Maybe your display doens't fit the requirements to be considered as a "large" layout, so Android won't load your files in layout-large folder but in layout folder instead since it is the default one. Try to create a folder called layout-xlarge and see if you have any difference, but I still recommend you to use `<dimen>` in a separate xml file instead of creating one layout for each screen size. Check this [article for multiple screen support](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more information.

Comment: many thanks @Murillo Henrique but I try adjustViewBounds and it's not working :(

Comment: @Ali maybe your display doens't fit the requirements to be considered as a "large" layout, so Android won't load your files in layout-large folder but in layout folder instead since it is the default one. Try to create a folder called layout-xlarge and see if you have any difference. If yes, I'll update this answer. Check this: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Sorry for late but I have it already and as I say before in layout-sw600dp you can see this:

Comment: <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="600dpi "
            android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

Comment: and actually I read all android articles for multi screen documents.I don't know why but non of them are work :(

Answer (score 0):

You should increase your ImageView size for value-sw600dp.
The normal value (200dp) and your provide images size is convert to around 100px in this case.
You can set layout_weight and and weightSum like this:

```
<LinearLayout  android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:weightSum="9"
    android:background="@drawable/dock_hold_main_icon" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_bus"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bus_main_icon" />
     ....
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout like above can make image scale by width size. 
Or you can change to use GridView or TableLayout

But I think it's better to calculate the size and set by code.

Comment: thanks for your help but can you tell me what different between  weight and weightSum ?

Comment: @Ali Basiclly, weightSum is size of parent view, layout_weight is the ratio of child views with parent. For exp: if parent's weightSum = 9, child's layout_weight = 2, so the child size will be 2/9 of the parent. You can read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696920/android-layout-layoutweight-and-weightsum for more detail

Comment: GOD NO. I change one of Linearlayout as you say nothing changed. I can't even understand why it's just for this one all other device is work perfect. actually it use 600dp layout is can be cause for the problem ?

Comment: @Ali, It's weird if nothing changed, you changed as I post above android:layout_width="0dp"? Also try to change scaleType="fitXy" if it can be better. It's not because of the 600dp layout, it's because for this device, screen density and screen resolution is high, while 200dp = 100px, and screen width is around 1000px so it's look small, you can try to increased to size of image( I think 400dp can be enough for this device but it's maybe too big for other). So I prefer to calculate and set the size by code base on screen's pixel witdh.

Comment: change size to 400dp in xml not work again !!!! I go for calculate and set the size by code .

Comment: Why increased size to 400dp not work? at least it's will increase the distance between your images.

Comment: It's not even make any change. I'm confusing too. I can't understand what happen !!! it's not scale or making space nothing but in xml showing in eclipse it's show the changes. actually I send it to my friend to test it on his device and send me the result. I say the result here.

Comment: my friend say his device is not make change any too. every think is the same.

Comment: Have you double-checked to make sure that you don't set textview3 in another folder is 600dpi too by accident? Change the text in textview3 to another value to check it.

Comment: Then from current state, I don't have any other guess to fix this.

Comment: I appreciated your help many thanks. I try to calculate in code and see the result. again many thanks.